# How to represent constants in UML class diagram?

Tags: c++, uml, class-diagram, headers

I am working on developing a UML class diagram from C++ code.  I have a classless header file that is basically a definitions file (it has structs, enums and defined constants).  I know how to represent structs and enums in general, but I am unclear about how to represent (or if I should represent) constants in the class diagram.  Additionally I am curious if the structs, enums and constants should be part of some larger container? (Like referencing the namespace helper or the definitions.h)

```
#ifndef DEFINITIONS_H
#define DEFINITIONS_H

#include <stdint.h>
#include <string>

namespace helper
{

  enum Colors
  {
    Red = 0,
    Blue,
    Green   
  };

  struct volunteer
  {
    std::string FirstName;
    std::string MiddleName;
    std::string LastName;
    std::string Occupation;
  };


  typedef const std::string Constant;
  Constant Foo = "Foo";
  Constant Bar = "Bar";
  Constant Bat = "Bat";
 }

#endif
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The goal of a class diagram is to document relationships between classes as well as how objects of those classes can change:

> In software engineering, a class diagram in the Unified Modeling
> Language (UML) is a type of static structure diagram that describes
> the structure of a system by showing the system's classes, their
> attributes, operations (or methods), and the relationships among
> objects.

<sup><sub>Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram)</sub></sup>

The key elements here are:

1. *Relationships* between classes: given a class, what other classes does it use?
2. *Operations* that can be performed on a class: what methods/functions belong to a class?
3. *State* belonging to a class: what data does a class encapsulate?

A constant does not fit into any of these elements.

It is not a *relationship*(1), and certainly not an *operation*(2). The closest element is *state*(3), but a constant is pretty much the opposite: it is static, and not tied to an object. While a *class* diagram documents classes, it is focused on elements of classes used by objects of those class types.

---

In your specific example, I would do the following:

- The `enum` would be a class in the diagram, but would likely be empty. The only state is the integer that represents each enum value, but that is essentially a surrogate key and not referenced in code. Note that if you use a C++ `enum class` instead, you might have state worth documenting.
- The `struct` should be a class with no behavior, but the state documented as public.
- **Those constants** should not be documented in a UML *class* diagram. For one, they do not belong to a class, making them completely irrelevant. Two, constants do not belong in a class diagram anyway for reasons I outlined above.
- I would create a separate [UML package diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_diagram) for `namespace helper` (as an aside, I recommend picking a more descriptive name for this namespace) showing that the `enum` and `struct` are in the namespace. This diagram type also allows for documenting static members in general and constants specifically.

Comment: UML has an own metatype `Enumeration` (see p. 165 of the UML 2.5 specs) and this should be used, not an empty class. A `struct` should preferable be stereotyped with `<<struct>>`.

Answer (score 3):

A class diagram is supposed to show an entity level model. A constant is a minor implementation detail and logically, it is not a member of the class, it bears no meaning in the OO view of things. So the answer is "you don't".

Answer (score 1):

Some of your `helper` information could be modeled as such:

[image]

The notion of a constant in UML exists, but it's usually inside a class and has a type. See the `Employee` class in the diagram above.

Answer (score 0):

I would represent them as objects (or "instances" in IBM Rational terminology) of class Constant or std::string (whichever seems more appropriate).  The object symbol can have the value added below the name.  You could mark the value as {read-only} if desired.